# How to create new class object for every new thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a programm written in C# which use for analysis text data from external API.
The main section looks like

**Main.cs**

```
void main {
 var data = new HttpRequest();
 while (true) {
  string response = data.Get("https://api.com/method/").ToString();
  JObject json = JObject.Parse(response);
  if (Convert.ToString(json["updates"][i]["type"]) == "message_new") {
   Data new_data = new Data();
   new_data.Text = json["updates"][i]["text"].ToString();
   .... //filling class new_data//....
   Thread thread = new Thread(() => ProcessMsg(new_data));
   thread.Start();

  } else { //nothing}
  }

 }
```

**Data Class**

```
 public class Data
    {

        public string Token = "alof23321cdfds34rf32rty5";
        public string Token_Usr = "fsdfdsf3432";
        public static string GroupId = "3331122";
        public int Time { get; set; }
        public int IdUser { get; set; }
        public int IdConf { get; set; }
        public int IdMessage { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
```

But very often (when 2 messages arrive at the same time) information is mixed in these threads (race condition?)
How to make the passed class in thread accessible only from this thread? Maybe I should use something else for this?

p.s do not pay attention to the code, I just tried to reproduce the logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a closure when you do `Thread thread = new Thread(() => ProcessMsg(new_data));`. If something changes `new_data` before the delegate is executed it will "see" the new version when run, what you are experiencing.

`Thread` has two constructors, one accepting a `ThreadStart` delegate and other accepting a `ParameterizedThreadStart` delegate and an object, in this case you want to use the later to pass the patameter to your thread function, something like this:

```
//...
Thread thread = new Thread(ProcessMsg, new_data);


//..
public void ProcessMsg(object State)
{
    var data = (Data)State;
    //Process the data
}
```